# ignoring WARNINGs in Django

Tags: django, warnings

Hay, my model is a through a "Data truncated for column 'password' at row 1" warning. This is fine, the data does get truncated, but it get fills back in by a different function later on.

How can i get django a ignore this warning? I think it's called on the Save() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you see there is from your backend database (looks like a mySQL warning to me).

I don't really think turning  database level warnings off is a good idea. You should probably make sure the data is NOT being truncated instead - Why let the system take junk data?

Comment: I got you, the field being truncated was a "password" field which contains a very long string (hex-digested), the data WAS actually being truncated to 50 chars (as per my model), this caused MAJOR problems and took about 30 mins for me to work out why this password field wasn't being matched against a user inputted password field!

Comment: I understand having the default be to display these warnings, but is there no way to override this? What if there is an emergency and I try to fix it but get bogged down with harmless mysql warnings?

Comment: This isn't really a general answer to the question. Truncating passwords in a database is bad. But in other cases, how do I ignore truncation warnings so an exception isn't thrown?

Comment: I have a good use case: we save monitoring messages in SQL, but we don't really need them. The actual message (JSON string) is processed in another part of the code. BUT, it can be useful to log other details of the message, even if one of the fields overflows its VARCHAR limit and is truncated. Since other exceptions can occur while processing messages, we wrap them in a try/except so we can continue with more msgs. With DataTruncation as Exception, the loop stops processing the message after logging it in the database. We could take out the DB portion, but we shouldn't have to.